# Memory limiting in Autodesk Forge-viewer causes anomalies in model display

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Select a node with memory limits attached to the Autodesk Forge-viewer.

If no memory limit is attached, it does not behave this way and
All nodes remain visible.

Then some of the unselected nodes will be hidden.

Do you know how to deal with this problem?

Default
All nodes is not hidden
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxrup.png)

After selecting nodes
Some nodes are hidden
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qWT7.png)

More information has been added
Detailed Description
[detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC2wO.png)

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What version of the viewer are you using, and how exactly are you configuring the MemoryLimited extension? Could you potentially share the design file with us (confidentially) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
We checked both 7.4 and 7.63 versions of the viewer and this occurred in both.
I can share design files and videos of it in action, but what else do you need?
I checked various files for the design file and it was the same.
The configuration of memory limited, etc. will be added as soon as they are known.

Comment: More information has been added Detailed Description.
See image in text